# react-native-image-crop-picker [!] [Xcodeproj] Generated duplicate UUIDs:

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

I installed react-native-image-crop-picker@0.33.1 on a bare project and if I run pod install
i got this UUID duplication that looks like:

[!] [Xcodeproj] Generated duplicate UUIDs:

PBXFileReference -- Pods.xcodeproj/mainGroup/children/children:children:|,|,|,|,|,displayName:CocoaAsyncSocket,isa:PBXGroup,name:CocoaAsyncSocket,path:CocoaAsyncSocket,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:CocoaLibEvent,isa:PBXGroup,name:CocoaLibEvent,path:CocoaLibEvent,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:DoubleConversion,isa:PBXGroup,name:DoubleConversion,path:DoubleConversion,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:Flipper,isa:PBXGroup,name:Flipper,path:Flipper,sourceTree:,,children:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,displayName:Flipper-DoubleConversion,isa:PBXGroup,name:Flipper-DoubleConversion, ...

Is there anyone who has this issue?

dependencies:

- "react": "16.13.1",
- "react-native": "0.63.2",
- "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.33.1"

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by the TOCropViewController pod. see: https://github.com/TimOliver/TOCropViewController/issues/424

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary fix (till TOCropViewController will be fixed) I've changed the file:
node_modules/react-native-image-crop-picker/RNImageCropPicker.podspec at line 16
from
s.dependency 'TOCropViewController'
to
s.dependency 'TOCropViewController', '2.5.3'

Then, I used the patch-package (https://github.com/ds300/patch-package) to create a patch with the changes.

Thx to [Constantin Predescu](https://github.com/predescu) as he wrote it at [Github](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker/issues/1359#issuecomment-666333218)